# How to ignore "useless storage class" with gcc using -Werror?

Tags: c, gcc, pragma

I compile my project with `-Werror` to make sure all of my code is without recognizable warnings. However my current project has a third-party dependency that has an issue in it which causes a warning - and that warning fails my build because of the `-Werror` flag.

I want to use the `-Werror` flag and I don't want to correct the third-party package. Is there a way to ignore this warning?

```
package.h:126:1: error: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [-Werror]
 };
```

The line of code that generates the error is a struct definition with a "dangling" typedef.

```
typedef struct my_data_obj {
  char* data;
  uint32_t data_size;
};
```

This is obviously a mistake - but I can't find any `pragma` or any such mechanic to ignore the warning generated from that header file. Any ideas?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Though I'm accepting Florian Weimer's answer because it answers the question most closely it's not the actual fix I settled with. I'll describe that bellow. By including the headers as system headers I did exactly what I wanted to do - suppress the error without having to fix the package.

What I finally did was create a patch file and simply apply that patch each time the project is built.

```
vim package.h
# fix the file
git add package.h
git diff --cached > package.h.patch

# on build time
git apply package.h.patch
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I would consider a *real* error, one that needs to be fixed. Why do you want to disable it instead of actually *fix* the problem?

Comment: Any local patching make subsequent imports from upstream more difficult. I can understand why people do not want to do this.

Comment: Because fixing it is trivial - and I would like to see if there is a way to ignore this as it certainly compiles without `-Werror`.

Comment: I suggest creating a wrapper header for your project that fixes up `package.h` (perhaps by suppressing the warning that it generates with `#pragma` before including the header), and then include the wrapper header in your project code.  You'll report the bug, of course.  Eventually, the bug may be fixed and you can then eliminate the wrapper header.  If you can rig things to ensure that the wrapper header is included in preference to the package's header, then you might be able to keep the same name.  Failing that, use a systematic name like `wrap-package.h`; it makes automatic editing easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want to include `package.h` from files where you want to enable `-Werror`.

GCC does not have a separate flag to control this warning, otherwise the compiler would have printed it.  With the separate flag, you could have used `#pragma GCC diagnostics ignore`, as indicated in the other answers, possibly with a wrapper header file.

However, you could put the header file into a separate directory, and instead of using `-I` to add it to the include path, use `-isystem`.  As a result, the header file is treated as a system header, and unless you also compile with `-Wsystem-headers`, warnings in system headers are suppressed.

Comment: And this makes a lot of sense when treating third-party headers as something one cannot or must not change -- that's practically the definition of a system header.  Moreover, this approach avoids simultaneously disabling the same warning for the project's own code.  If you disable warnings then it should be because that kind of warning does not matter to you, not because they occur in a file you're not concerned with.

Answer (score -1):

All warnings and errors have specific names, and can be enabled or disabled on a per-warning/-error basis.

For example lets say I have an unused variable and enabled warnings about it, then I will get a message similar to

```
/some/path/main.cpp:18:9: warning: unused variable ‘i’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

That last part of the message, the one inside the square brackets, is the name of the specific warning.

With this name you can then disable warnings using the `-Wno-<name of warning>` option. In the case of the above warning it's disabled with `-Wno-unused-variable`.

Your use-case is a *little* different in that you want to disable a warning turned into an *error*. This is very similar to the above, but the general form of the option is `-Wno-error=<name of warning or error>`. In our example case it's `-Wno-error=unused-variable`.

All of this is of course [in the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/), more specifically [in the warning options documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

So what you have to do is figure out the name of the warning, so you can use it for the `-Wno-error=` option.

Comment: *All warnings and errors have specific names*: This is not actually true and is the problem here.